# UIAlertView button to another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have in my application a uialertview, that has two buttons, the first one is cancel button , and the second one is ok. when i press on OK button, I want to go to the view controller which has a storyboard identifier "RootView", but it doesn't work.
I put this below code in the appdelegate.m method.

```
- (void)showAlarm:(NSString *)text {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"show alarm"
                                                            message:text delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];


        [alertView show];
    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

        if (buttonIndex == 0){
             NSLog(@"cancel"); 

        }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
             NSLog(@"ok");
           UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


           UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];


            [navigationController presentViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootView"] animated:YES completion:nil];


        }
    }
```

Comment: whether log prints "ok" or not?

Comment: yes, it prints, it works, but the action which is navigate to another view controller doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my sample code it works for me

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self showAlert];
    return YES;
}
-(void)showAlert
{
    UIAlertView *alertForCall = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"time to choose" delegate:self   cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:@"NO", nil];
    [alertForCall show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        self.viewController = [[NewsTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsTestViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *testNavi = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = testNavi;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you should be using `didDismissWithButtonIndex` rather `clickedButtonAtIndex`. The former is invoked *after* the UIAlertView has been removed from the screen hierarchy, while the latter occurs while the UIAlertView is still on screen. While on screen, UIAlertView alters the nature of the app; that means bad things happen when trying to push views to the nav controller.

Answer (score 3):

Do you wanna push the new view controller ou present it modally? Assuming the last, maybe this helps you:

```
RootView *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootView"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I was going to add my own answer but @leoformaggio basically nailed it. 

To further extend the answer, looking at your code you are creating both a nav controller and view controller. You are right in that you are putting the view controller in the nav controller but you forgot to add the nav controller to the view stack. Without adding the nav controller to the stack nothing is going to happen.